# Chrome inspect window toolbars shrunken and cannot restore to default

Tags: google-chrome

The devtools window or the inspect window on Chrome on my Mac somehow shrank when I accidentally hit some combination of keys and swipes, as you can see from the picture below. I have tried focusing on the inspect window and doing control+shift++ and control+shift+0 as instructed on the Chrome documentation, but they do not work.

There must be some control on the toolbar in devtools but it is too small for me to see.

How do I restore the inspect window to the original default zoom?

[image: Chrome devtools screen shot]

Comment: If you're on a Mac, try hitting `cmd+0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd+0` is the solution here, since this is the hotkey to restore zoom on a Mac.